# マルチプロセスサーバでのプロセス間コネクション共有問題

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

[このコミット](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/aaff1a4101605b7d2e2386d3e7612a43fbe07c8d#diff-7735c67f539e7d1e2908a4d5d8909c24)でプロセスごとにconnection_poolが管理されるようになったように見えます。
Rails4以降、Unicornなどのマルチプロセスサーバにおける以下の設定は必要なくなったのでしょうか？

```
after_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is *required* for Rails + "preload_app true",
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```